# Keycloak admin api cannot set role mapping while creating user

Tags: angular, keycloak

I want to create user using api but i have a problem with setting realm roles to the user.

```
http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/microservicedb/users

{
    "username": "abc3",
    "email": "ab3@gmail.com",
    "realmRoles": [
        "admin", "employee"
    ],
    "credentials": [{
        "type": "password",
        "temporary": true,
        "value": "testpass"
    }],
    "enabled": true
}
```

while trying with this api the user will be created successfully but the "admin" and "employee" role are custom created role in realm role are not mapped to the user.

```
{
    "username": "roletest",
    "email": "roletest@gmail.com",
    "realmRoles": [
        "5bb0da62-86e4-4f90-b349-fcec4f3ac8b9", "31d0879d-ff8f-48cf-adb6-a9c996887ba4"
    ],
    "credentials": [{
        "type": "password",
        "temporary": true,
        "value": "testpass"
    }],
    "enabled": true
}
```

tried using with role id but the result is same
user created without custom realmRole mapping

Comment: Have you tried using the `id` of the role you want to set?

Comment: is id available for role. where can i see that

Comment: You can find it either by querying the realm role endpoint or look at the url in the admin ui. You can find the id in the url when editing realm roles